# can't find _id attribute in the array of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple schema of blog with embedded comments, which is modeled in mongoose

```
var BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          ...............,
         comments:[Comment],
         visits:int  
});

var Comment = mongoose.Schema({
    name  :  { type: String }
  , img   :  { type:String }
  , date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , text  :  String 
});


var BlogModel = mongoose.model('Blog',BlogSchema);

function addComment(bid,name,img,text,callback){

    var options = { new: false };       
    BlogModel.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':bid},{'$push':{'comments':{'name':name,'img':img,'text':text}},'$inc':{'visits':1}},options,function(err,ref){
        if(err) {
            console.log('add addComment'.red,err);
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            console.log('add addComment  '.green+ref);                
            callback(null,ref);
        }
    })  
}
```

When I post a comment on the blog, the comments array in the blog did append the new comment with name,img and text attribute. But the problem is the date and _id are missing for some reason. With the _id on each comment, it is possible to re-edit or delete this comment, so _id is very necessary.

I don't know why date is gone, because in the schema design, date is default to new Date, and also _id should not be missed out that I don't force the _id entry to be ignored like this way -  mongoose.Schema({ _id:false});

Now the results for me are wired, can some body look what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the `update` calls (e.g. `findOneAndUpdate`) bypass all the Mongoose functionality beyond casting, like defaults and adding the `_id` field to new elements.  You'd have to use a `save` style change for those to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny, now I get it